# (Newbie) Troubleshooting BS4 script - ValueError: unknown url type: '/logo.gif'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a script that opens a URL (depending on the number you input) and then downloads a specific image.

If I could get help in the right direction (so I can learn), I would greatly appreciate it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib.request

cas = input("Please enter a CAS no.")
print(cas)
casStr = str(cas)
url = f"https://www.chemicalbook.com/SpectrumEN_{casStr}_1HNMR.htm"

page = requests.get(url)

if page.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
else:
    print("Unknown error.")


images = soup.find_all("img")

for image in images:
    image_src = image["src"]
    print(image_src)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src)
```

Upon running this, I get the error

```
ValueError: unknown url type: '/logo.gif'
```

The "Cas no." I am unputting is

```
100-39-0
```

Comment: It means what it says. What do you expect to get from `/logo.gif` if you put it in your browser?

Comment: Also, you're using `requests` but you're not importing it. On the other hand, you've imported `os` but you're not using it. What's more, the second`soup` can be undefined, move it to the `if` block. Finally, you might greatly benefit from reading [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Using this `if image["src"].startswith('http'):` line just before `image_src = image["src"]` should fix the problem you are having. You will miss some images in that case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what everyone else said about errors you might run into in your code, the issue you're running into is that most `src` attributes are relative links.

The `img` you've found is `<img src="/logo.gif">`.
The source attribute is `/logo.gif`, and the requests library will not prepend the root domain for you.

So really you just have to change the first line in your `for loop`:

```
for image in images:
    image_src = "https://www.chemicalbook.com/" + image["src"]
    print(image_src)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src)
```